# How can i get my registration form page to work with php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, mysqli

please i'm kinda new to website development. i tried to create a registration page to work with my database but my registration form page is not responding to the php coding page.
please i need your assistance. thank

**This is my registration.html page**
i don't know if the error is from my registration form page

```
<form action="student.php" name="register" id="register" method="POST" data-aos="fade">
              <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3 mb-lg-0">
                  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" required>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <input type="text" name="studentid" id="studentid" class="form-control" placeholder="Student ID" value="" required>
                </div>
              </div>
             <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <input type="text" name="level" class="form-control" placeholder="Level" required>
                </div>
              </div>
             <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <p class="mb-0">Gender</p>
                     <input name="gender" type="radio"  value="m" required> Male
                     <input name="gender" type="radio"  value="f" required> Female
                    
                </div>
              </div>
             <div class="form-group row">
                <div id="date-picker" class="col-md-12 md-form md-outline input-with-post-icon datepicker" inline="true">
                  <input type="text" name="dob" class="form-control" id="date9" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" required>
                  <i class="fas fa-calendar input-prefix"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
                <script>
                    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                        inline: true;
                    });
                    </script>
                
             <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" value="" required>
                </div>
              </div>
             <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <input type="phone" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" class="form-control" placeholder="+234 8179 5523 71" required>
                </div>
              </div>
             <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <input type="department" name="department" class="form-control" placeholder="Department" required>
                </div>
              </div>
             <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <input type="password" name="password" value=""  id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                </div>
              </div>
             <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
                </div>
              </div>
                
              <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-5 btn-block btn-pill" value="SUBMIT">
                    
                </div>
              </div>

            </form>
```

**This is my Php page for the form**
or maybe the error is from my php code. please help detect the problem guys. Thanks.

```
<?php
session_start();

// initializing variables
$studentid = "";
$email    = "";
$errors = array(); 

// connect to the database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'oneschool');

// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  // receive all input values from the form
  $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['firstname']);
  $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['lastname']);
  $studentid = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['studentid']);
  $level = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['level']);
  $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['gender']);
  $dob = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['dob']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
  $phonenumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['phonenumber']);
  $department = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['department']);
  $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
  $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['confirmpassword']);

  // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled ...
  // by adding (array_push()) corresponding error unto $errors array
  if (empty($studentid)) { array_push($errors, "Student ID is required"); }
  if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required"); }
  if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }
  if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
    array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
  }

  // first check the database to make sure 
  // a user does not already exist with the same username and/or email
  $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM student_registra WHERE studentid='$studentid' OR email='$email' LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query) or die(mysqli_error($db));
  $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  
  if ($user) { // if user exists
    if ($user['studentid'] === $studentid & $user['email'] === $email) {
      array_push($errors, "Student Id already taken");
    }

    if ($user['email'] === $email) {
      array_push($errors, "email already exists");
    }
  }

  // Finally, register user if there are no errors in the form
  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database

    $query = "INSERT INTO student_registra (firstname, lastname, studentid, level, gender, dob, email, phonenumber, department, password) 
              VALUES('$firstname', '$lastname', '$studentid', '$level', '$gender', '$dob', '$email', '$phonenumber', '$department', '$password')";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $_SESSION['studentid'] = $studentid;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "Registration Sucessful";
    header('location: index.html');
  }
}
```

i don't know what seems to be the problem, because i run it the first time it worked, but when i shutdown my laptop and turn it on back again after my lunch, it stop working.
Instead of it to read the .php code it's rather displaying the whole .php code and i've checked the code, i can't find what seems to be the problem.
please guys, i'll need your help in fixing this or detecting the problem.
thanks

Comment: The start of your HTML form appears to be missing, could you edit it so it includes the beginning `<form>` tag?

Comment: it has been edited. please help cross check for my errors

Comment: Please see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT, You have a lot of useless codes that make your code so slow, Like $_SESSION['success']; This is not neccessary, Change your index.html to index.php and delete it because it do nothing, You can check session by student id** You have two gender Inputs, how comes you assign one of them? This is first mistake
Secondly, Use Prepared Statements to avoid  SQLI Attacks
Thirdly How comes you header a html page when you're in php page? change index.html to index.php

And Use this code instead:

```php
 if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database
    $prepared = "INSERT INTO student_registra (firstname, lastname, studentid, level, gender, dob, email, phonenumber, department, password) 
              VALUES('$firstname', '$lastname', '$studentid', '$level', '$gender', '$dob', '$email', '$phonenumber', '$department', '$password')";

    $query = $prepared;
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $_SESSION['studentid'] = $studentid;
    # Change your files index.html To index.php
    header('location: index.php');
  }
```